# Calling a web service that has list of a model as a parameter to a web form

Tags: c#

my service looks like this...

```
    [WebMethod]
    public bool insertRecord(List<People> stu)
    {
        using (LearnershipDBEntities dn = new LearnershipDBEntities())
        {
            Person obj = new Person();

            foreach (var item in stu)
            {
                obj.personID = item.personId;
                obj.dateOfBirth = item.dob;
                obj.idNumber = item.idNumber;
                obj.name = item.name;
                obj.title = item.title;
            }

            dn.People.Add(obj);
            dn.SaveChanges();

        }

        return true;
    }
```

my form has this code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ToDbXml.Service2 nb = new ToDbXml.Service2();
           Service2Client s = new Service2Client();

            People dto = new People();

            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {                   
                dto.name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) ? string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                dto.dob = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()) ? (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Null : DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                dto.title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) ? string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                dto.idNumber = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()) ? string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();                                     
            }

            s.insertRecord(dto); 


            MessageBox.Show("Values Inserted Succesfully");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show( ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

i am getting this error when i hover around my object that i'm passing to my service. cannot convert from people to people[]

Comment: the error message clearly says that you have to pass array/list of people

Comment: also the add statement should be inside foreach loop in `insertRecord` function

Comment: thanks man let me try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct a list of People and pass it to the webservice method. So I suggest you to modify the source code of your web service like this :

```
[WebMethod]
public bool insertRecord(List<People> stu)
{
    using (LearnershipDBEntities dn = new LearnershipDBEntities())
    {
        Person obj = new Person();

        foreach (var item in stu)
        {
            obj.personID = item.personId;
            obj.dateOfBirth = item.dob;
            obj.idNumber = item.idNumber;
            obj.name = item.name;
            obj.title = item.title;
            dn.People.Add(obj);
        }

        dn.SaveChanges();

    }

    return true;
}
```

And the event button handler like this :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ToDbXml.Service2 nb = new ToDbXml.Service2();
        Service2Client s = new Service2Client();
        List<People> listOfPeople = new List<People>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {    
            listOfPeople.add (
            new People() 
            {

            name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) ? string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
            dob = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()) ? (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.Null : DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()),
            title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()) ? string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
            idNumber = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()) ? string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()
          });

        }
        s.insertRecord(listOfPeople); 
        MessageBox.Show("Values Inserted Succesfully");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show( ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Hope this would fix your issues.

Comment: You are welcom. If my answer helped you, please marke it as the correcte answer. Thanks!